# Ошибка TS2740 при инициализация массива

Tags: typescript

**Ошибка:** TS2740: Type '{ props: { icon: string; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'IconLink': render, context, setState, forceUpdate, and 2 more.
(ошибка на линии: "{props: {icon: "https://"}}", в файле: `App.tsx`)
P.s: `<IconLink icon=""/>` - работает

**Файл** `IconLink.tsx`:

```
interface IconLinkProps extends AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>{
  icon: string
}
```

```
class IconLink extends React.Component<IconLinkProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <a {...this.props}>
        <img src={this.props.icon} alt=" "/>
        {this.props.children}
      </a>
    );
  }
}
```

**Файл** `App.tsx` (с ошибкой)

```
let array: IconLink[] = [
  {props: {icon: "https://"}}
];
```

Comment: `IconLink` - это компонент, а ты пытаешься в него простой объект запихнуть ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const navs: IconLink[] = [
  new IconLink({icon: ""})
]
```

Это решило проблему